# Controlling a random webpage through a Perl script

Tags: perl, file, search-engine, html

There is a random website say abc.com and this website has a search engine. Is it possible to create a perl script to automatically read from a text file and feed search values into this search engine and automatically download the files that are the result of the search ? Once the download is complete, the loop has to continue until all the search values have been exhausted. I don't have any server details about the website itself.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: It's possible.  What have you tried?  Have you searched on CPAN for useful modules?

Comment: Yes I found this module -> http://search.cpan.org/~prashant/Win32-IEAutomation-0.4/lib/Win32/IEAutomation.pm, this had pretty much all I was looking for. Was not sure if its just specific to google or can be used on any webpage.

Comment: I'd be thinking `WWW::Mechanize`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is HTTP client programming. You're basically writing a program that is pretending to be a browser.

The standard module for doing this is probably [WWW::Mechanize](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize) (see the [cookbook](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/WWW-Mechanize/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Cookbook.pod) and the [examples](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/WWW-Mechanize/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Examples.pod)).

If you want something lower level, then the [LWP](https://metacpan.org/release/libwww-perl) bundle of modules will do all that you want.

There's a [free online book](http://lwp.interglacial.com/). But it's a little old and probably doesn't reflect current best practices.